# Bitlocker disk encryption without admin override

Tags: security, encryption, windows-8, active-directory, windows-8.1

I am a somewhat paranoid CTO exec that just received a Microsoft Surface with Windows 8.1 and I would like to enable disk encryption to protect my information. I know that bitlocker can be enabled to prevent access from external sources, but I'm just as concerned about internal sources.

I know my system administrators can see all of my e-mail and all my network activity, and I'm okay with that. However, I do not want them to be able to access my machine while I'm not around using a system admin account, as I have a personal dropbox account and of course I am constantly logged into personal websites at home.

How can I enable bitlocker and ensure that no one but myself ever has access to my data without my knowledge?

Things to think about: System admin logging in directly on machine, system admin taking over my session remotely, system admin changing my domain password and logging in with my credentials. I want to protect against any and all unauthorized access except for myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can encrypt files using your user account (Properties, Encrypt; this is not the same as BitLocker), which will prevent any other user from reading the file.

This encryption is based on your login password; if an admin changes your password without entering the old password, the encryption key will be destroyed.

Note that a malicious admin can still install a keylogger.

Comment: if I check details of folder it shows a recovery certificate (administrator@domain) as defined by recovery policy. Does this mean my admin can still get in even though I'm using EFS?